# rxplot not found

Tags: ros, tutorial, rxplot, rosserial, ir

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed Indigo on Ubuntu 14.4 and I'm doing the rosserial IR ranger tutorial. When I execute

rxplot range_data/range

I get

rxplot not found.

I gather this command has been superceded by rqt_plot. If so what would the proper command line be.

Thanks

RoboBill

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201721/rxplot-not-found/) by [RoboBill](https://answers.ros.org/users/21253/robobill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rqt_plot is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for rxplot in most situations. Try:

```
rqt_plot range_data/range
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2